# jQuery upload PDF with FormData?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am attempting to upload a file through jQuery to my remote server, but I can't seem to get it working.

The user needs to be able to upload a pdf file, which will then be processed by the server and saved to the root folder.

**jQuery**

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
        },
        url: 'http://www.codekraken.com/testing/pointify/test.php?callback=?',
        data: fd,
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$name = $_FILES["fd"]["name"];
echo ($_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($name).')');
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I submit a file, such as `input.pdf` and then press submit, I get the response `(null)`. I would expect to get the name of the file, `input.pdf`, which means I am missing a crucial step in this process.

Comment: Are you testing with a browser that supports that type of upload? (Anything but IE < 10)

Comment: The HTML is being run from `localhost` however, if that matters...

Comment: do you get null, or do you get an object that contains a responseText property that is null. If it's just null, that means you're getting to the success callback. At that point, i'd do more debugging on the php side.

Comment: I think having `callback=?` in the url makes a `jsonp` request. Which is a GET not a POST, you would want to make a POST when uploading files.

Comment: @KevinB I get `null`, not an object containing `null`.

Comment: That too, you can't POST with JSONP

Comment: @Musa Then how can I post from `localhost`? Or any domain that's not my own?

Comment: Use Cross origin resource sharing.

Comment: The cross-domain server would need to support CORS, otherwise it isn't possible. also note, CORS doesn't work 100% in all browsers.

Comment: @KevinB I enabled it in the PHP file by using `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` and the JS file by using `$.support.cors = true;`, but I am getting this error when trying to make the request: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.codekraken.com/testing/pointify/test.php. Request header field pragma is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

Comment: Ah, turns out I can't set any headers when making this type of request. So deleting the `beforeSend:` parameter solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this

```
$name = $_FILES["fd"]["name"];
```

should be

```
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Comment: This might be a problem, but it's not the problem. Apparently JSONP is only for getting, not posting

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make this visible, so I'm answering the major problem of the question.

`JSONP` is only for requests, so `POST` wouldn't work with it. Subsequently, you can use `CORS` to solve the problem.

[I found a site](http://enable-cors.org/index.html) that lists many types of servers that you can enable `CORS` on, which I would suggest looking into.

For my case, I used the following header in my PHP code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

That opens up that page to all requests, but it still wasn't working with my jQuery `AJAX` code. To remedy this, I had to remove the part of my code that set headers, which apparently isn't allowed when making these requests. So, I deleted this part:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
        },
```